# JSON data returns empty string when authorizing my channel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am getting an error in javascript: Pusher: ["JSON returned from auth endpoint was invalid, yet status code was 200. Data was: "] so empty data. I have uncommented the broadcasting service provider and provided with a following channel route:

```
Broadcast::channel('MessageChannel.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return $user->id == $id;
});
```

My Messaging.vue has the following lines:

```
      let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

      const pusher = new Pusher(this.$store.state.pusherKey, {
        cluster: 'eu',
        forceTLS: true,
        authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
        auth: {
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': token.content
          }
        }
      });

      const channel = pusher.subscribe('private-MessageChannel.'+this.$store.state.user.id);
      channel.bind('new-message', response => {
        this.appendMessage(response);
      });
      channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(status) {
        console.log(status);
      });
```

Just to note, it all works with events and stuff when using a PUBLIC channel, but not private, which I want to use.

Comment: Show routes/channels.php please.

Comment: i did its at the top

Comment: even if i remove all the channels from the routes/channels.php file, its the same response

Comment: Do you have this line `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);`?

Comment: i get error 500 when i add this line

Comment: anyone? i have no more ideas

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. To be honest, I dont know what the problem was, but its now working.

My channel is as follows:

```
Broadcast::channel('MessageChannel.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
  return $user->id == $id;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add user's token to laravel echo headers.

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': token.content,
    Authorization: `Bearer {token_here}`
}
```